# How to explain the result of this tensorflow program?

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1)
x = x + 1
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    print(sess.run(x))
    print(sess.run(x))
```

The output is

```
2
2
```

But I think the output should be

```
2
3
```

The first run, x has been update to 2, and the second run, x should be 3.
Who can tell me why the second run of x is 2 either? If x can't be update by the first run, how is the parameter of neural network update?

### Update

```
x = tf.Variable(1)
x.assign(x+1)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    #print(x)
    print(sess.run(x))
    print(sess.run(x))
```

The output is

```
1
1
```

It is amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an analysis of your and Ishant Mrinal examples, it should help you understand what's going on here.

## Example 1

```
x = tf.Variable(1)
```

Creation of a python variable `x`. Creation of a Tensorflow node `variable_1`. The python variable `x` holds a logical pointer to the node `variable_1`.

```
x = x + 1
```

Python assignment, destructive operation.

`x` now holds a pointer to the operation `sum(variable_1, constant(1))`.

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
```

usual code of initialization of variables.

```
    print(sess.run(x))
```

Execution of `x` = execution of `sum(variable_1, constant(1))` = 2

```
    print(sess.run(x))
```

Execution of `x` = execution of `sum(variable_1, constant(1))` = 2

## Example 2

```
x = tf.Variable(1)
```

Creation of a python variable `x`. Creation of a Tensorflow node `variable_1`. The python variable `x` holds a logical pointer to the node `variable_1`.

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

initialization of `variable_1`.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
   init.run()
```

execution of the initialization.

```
    # here x point to the variable
    print(sess.run(x))
```

evaluation of `x` = 1.

```
    x = x + 1
```

Definition of a new node, exactly as in the previous example.

```
    print(sess.run(x))
```

evaluation of the sum operation, thus `2`.

## Example 3

```
x = tf.Variable(1)
```

usual creation.

```
as_op = x.assign(x+1)
```

definition of a sum node followed by the definition of  an assignment node, held by the python variable `as_op`.

This operation forces the order of execution between these 2 nodes. First executes the sum node, then use the result to assign it to the node variable `variable_1`.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
```

usual init ops

```
    # here x point to the variable
    print(sess.run(x))
```

evaluation of `variable_1`, thus `1`.

```
sess.run(as_op)
```

execution of sum and assigment, thus `temp = variable_1 + 1; variable_1 = temp`;

```
print(sess.run(x))
```

extraction of the value pointed to x, thus `2`.

Comment: Prefect explaination.

Answer (score 0):

> tensorflow `add` op returns a updated `tensor`

```
x = x + 1 
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    print(x)
    # here x is a addition op; hence the result same for both run
    > result Tensor("add:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
    for both run x is just the same add op
    print(sess.run(x))  # result: 2
    print(sess.run(x))  # result: 2
```

> if you change the location of the addition op then values will be different; since you will accessing initial value and updated value from the `add` op

```
x = tf.Variable(1)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    # here x point to the variable
    print(sess.run(x))  # result: 1
    x = x + 1
    # here x point to the add op
    print(sess.run(x))  # result: 2
```

> Using assign op to get the updated value

```
x = tf.Variable(1)
as_op = x.assign(x+1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    # here x point to the variable
    print(sess.run(x)) # result: 1
    sess.run(as_op)    # variable updated
    print(sess.run(x)) # result: 2
```

Comment: No, x is a tensor. `Tensor("add:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)` not an ops.

Comment: But parameter of nerual network can be update, it just define one time.

Comment: No! the `optimizer` implement similar logic as `assign` inside.

Comment: Oh my god, it means `x=x+1` is not the same as `as_op = x.assign(x+1)`, I'm still confused.